# Dúvidas sobre redirecionamento com location.replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou enviando um form com AJAX e após o envio, e o retorno JSON for positivo, o usuário é redirecionado, estou usando o método `window.location.replace(redir_url)`, porém ainda estou conseguindo voltar à página anterior e ver o formulário que já foi enviado preenchido, o que fazer para que o usuário seja redirecionado e não possa voltar no histórico?

Comment: Por que não limpar o FORM depois de submeter? **http://stackoverflow.com/a/8701877/6054930**

Comment: Essa sugestão ^ é melhor mesmo. Levemente relacionado: não deveria haver problema nenhum do seu usuário voltar e encontrar of form enviado. Desenhe o seu sistema de forma que se isso acontecer ele não possa tomar nenhuma atitude que comprometa o sistema. Não dá pra confiar nem na implementação de cada navegador nem na destreza (por vezes acidental) dos usuários.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela sugestão, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Mesclo o reset() com o replace?

Comment: Pelo o que eu entendi, eu só posso usar o reset no método post? é porque eu estou usando o form com o plugin de upload do Dropzone que trabalha com o formulário diferente.